# PrimeFaces autocomplete not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following on my xhtml:

```
<p:outputLabel for="concept" value="Concept" />
        <p:autoComplete id="concept"
            value="#{cCRX1Controller.ccrx1.tbcodigo}"
            completeMethod="#{cCRX1Controller.completeConcepts}" var="concept"
            itemLabel="#{concept.tbdesc}" itemValue="#{concept.tbcodigo}"
            requiredMessage="You must select a concept."
            required="#{request.getParameter('validate')}" />
```

The completeConcepts method looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<CCRX1> completeConcepts(String query)
{
    ccrx1.setConcepts(service.getConcepts(query));

    System.out.println(query);

    return ccrx1.getConcepts();
}
```

The method above is my controller class where I have it declare as @ManagedBean and @ViewScoped and I am initializing my service class. The service.getConcepts(query) method looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<CCRX1> getConcepts(String query)
{
    String sqlConcepts = "SELECT TBCODIGO, TBDESC, TBIOE FROM CCRX1 WHERE STATUS <> 'I' "
            + "AND QOFICINA IN ('', ?) AND TBDESC LIKE '%?%'";

    ArrayList<CCRX1> listC = new ArrayList<CCRX1>();

    try {
        conn = ConnectionDB.getDS().getConnection();

        prstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlConcepts);

        prstmt.setString(1, "0101");

        prstmt.setString(2, query);

        rs = prstmt.executeQuery();

        // setting the data from CCRX1
        while (rs.next()) {

            CCRX1 c = new CCRX1();

            c.setTbcodigo(rs.getString("TBCODIGO"));

            c.setTbdesc(rs.getString("TBDESC"));

            c.setTbioe(rs.getString("TBIOE"));

            listC.add(c);

        }

        // close resources
        prstmt.close();

        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            prstmt.close();

            rs.close();

            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return listC;
}
```

The CCRX1 class looks like this:

```
public class CCRX1 {

    private String tbcodigo;

    private String tbdesc;

    private String tbioe;

    private String tbqcon;

    private List<CCRX1> concepts = new ArrayList<CCRX1>();

    public String getTbcodigo() {
        return tbcodigo;
    }

    public void setTbcodigo(String tbcodigo) {
        if (tbcodigo == null)
            this.tbcodigo = tbcodigo;

        else
            this.tbcodigo = tbcodigo.trim();
    }

    public String getTbdesc() {
        return tbdesc;
    }

    public void setTbdesc(String tbdesc) {
        if (tbdesc == null)
            this.tbdesc = tbdesc;

        else
            this.tbdesc = tbdesc.trim();
    }

    public String getTbioe() {
        return tbioe;
    }

    public void setTbioe(String tbioe) {
        if (tbioe == null)
            this.tbioe = tbioe;

        else
            this.tbioe = tbioe.trim();
    }

    public List<CCRX1> getConcepts() {
        return concepts;
    }

    public void setConcepts(List<CCRX1> concepts) {
        this.concepts = concepts;
    }

    public String getTbqcon() {
        return tbqcon;
    }

    public void setTbqcon(String tbqcon) {
        this.tbqcon = tbqcon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tbcodigo;
    }

}
```

If you notice, on the completeConcepts method I have a System.out.println(). When I start typing something on the field, it is not returning anything to the console. It is not giving me any error message or nothing. What am I missing?

I am using this link as a guide: [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) I am using PrimeFaces 5.3 and JSF 2.2.

Comment: I can see here you didn't use a converter

Comment: But is that why I can't even display in the console the Query parameter been passed from the form @AliHelmy?

Comment: I didn't see that you are using the itemValue as String not an object . sorry

Comment: Can you change the return type of complete method to `List` not `ArrayList`

Comment: I tried that and that is not the problem

Comment: Can you please show the CCRX1 class?. If you are using the item label and item value as two different String . You  have to follow one of the approach 1) Override toString in CCRX1 2) Use the Converter . I think you didn't use the converter.

Comment: since you are using itemlabel and itemvalue change the value to an object and use a converter  value="#{cCRX1Controller.OBJECT}"

Comment: none of those helped